# Finding prime numbers: segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have a program that finds and prints prime numbers from a predefined scope:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int scope = 90;

    std::vector<int> arr;

    int n = 2;

    for (int i = n; i < scope; i++)
    {
        arr.push_back(i);
    }

    int index = 0;
    while ((n * n) <= scope)
    {
        int size = (int)arr.size();
        for (int i = index + 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] % n == 0)
            {
                arr.erase(arr.begin() + i);
            }
        }

        index += 1;
        n = arr[index];
    }

    int final_size = (int)arr.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < final_size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

it works fine but only when the scope is <= 90. When it is larger than 90 I get an error:

```
zsh: segmentation fault
```

I am a beginner and can't figure out reason for this. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What updates `size` when you remove things from `arr` in your loop?

Comment: @StephenNewell Thanks! Now I understand what was the problem